# Shared variables within subclasses in java

Tags: java, android, inheritance, subclassing

I currently have a parent class which has two subclasses and what I essentially want to do is have them both inherit a shared variable (a float). I need to set the value of the float in subclass1 and then use the value of the float in subclass2. I should add that these are all android activities and that subclass1 is at the beginning of a chain of activities and subclass2 is at the end of this chain, all the activities in between are also children of the same parent class.

What I currently have is something similar to the following:
(I've left a lot of the other code out this is just the bare bones)

```
class activityParent extends Activity{
    public static float value;

    public void setValue(){

        //grab the value from phone (ill leave this code out and will hardcode a value below as an example)
        value = 0.6f;
    }

    public void useValue(){
        //where i use the value in another function here
        otherFuncion(value);
    }

}

class subclass1 extends activityParent 
{
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
         setValue();//need this to be initialized first
         super.onCreate(bundle);

    }
}

class subclass2 extends activityParent{
    //some previous code here
    //i need to use the value just before the activity finishes
    useValue();
    finish();

}
```

That float value is never used anywhere else.

This approach just seems wrong and I know it but I'm not sure how to go about implementing this properly.

I was thinking about passing data with intents but as mentioned the two subclasses arent in direct contact with each other, theres a series of activities between them and I'd rather not have to string this data through them all just to reach the end.

Comment: I know this is probably not a good practice, but you can write the value in a file and read it in another activity.

Comment: I don't see the problem of the approach. You have a static variable and you can access it from anywhere and anytime without passing to any activity. Or maybe your question is not clear enough!

Comment: Agree with @NguyenDoanTung. If you think it's evil to have static fields, I would suggest use a singleton data container class or take use of SharedPreferences (simplest persistent storage in Android) to store and fetch the value.

Answer (score 0):

There is FAQ discussed in below link.

[How do I pass data between Activities/Services within a single application?](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3)

Ideally, since you want to share a **primitive data** type (a float), **Intent** is recommended. But since this does not fit well with your requirement, you may skip this.

Next, using "static" (which you are currently doing) is also fine. You can access these static fields from any other class in your application.

But, if you want to have an alternate, then "Singleton" class can be used. This is a class that is designed to have only one instance.

```
public  class Singleton {
    private static  Singleton INSTANCE ;
 
    private Singleton() {}
 
    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
        if(INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = new Singleton();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
        
    }
}
```

It has a static method with a name such as getInstance() that returns the instance; the first time this method is called, it creates the global instance.

For example activity subclass1 may retrieve the instance and call setValue(0.6); later activity subclass2 may retrieve the instance and call getValue() to retrieve the last set value.

Answer (score 0):

Be very carefull with a cascade of classes. The `onCreate()` of a `SubClass1` calls `super.onCreate()` which is the `onCreate()` of `ActivityParent`. This may trigger a chain reaction (the intent calling `ActivityParent` is still available to `onCreate()`).

Comment: This should be a comment.